# How to compare the timestamp of a file against a threshold value(minutes from current time) in a Windows script?

Tags: timestamp, compare, windows-scripting

In windows script need to make decision based on a file timestamp against a threshold value (in minutes from current timestamp).

If a file timestamp has not been updated for a number of minutes an action must be taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux it takes a few lines but in Windows there is not an easy way to do this. In general Windows is very bad script-wise related to date/time processing.

I ended up using forfiles command (which allows using /D option +/- days) to grab files but then needed to manually parse timestamps and dates. 
There are some utilities by Rob vad der Woude which can be used.